# Как отдельно загрузить файлы в форму и получить их в php

Tags: php

index.php

```
<form action="index2.php" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='file' name='input_files[]'>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

index2.php

```
$files = $_FILES['input_files']['name'];
for($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++){
    echo $files[$i];
}
```

Например я выбрал определенный файл и как мне сделать чтобы при повторном выборе другого файла , в
php отправлялся не последний выбранный файл , а оба.

Comment: Зачем отправлять оба файла?

Comment: @u_mulder например , один файл в одной папке , а другой файл в другой папке.

Comment: это вам JS нужен, а не PHP. PHP серверный язык. после того как страница была отправлена пользователю - php уже не работает. а вот после получения страницы с содержимым можно работать например через JS

Comment: И на что влияет что файлы в разных папках?